# Finding the eigenvalues for a $3\times 3$ matrix

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

With the matrix $A$ given by $$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & a \\
1 & 0 & 1 \end{array} \right)$$

the solution to the initial value problem $x'=Ax$, $x(0) = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 \\
-1\\
b \end{array} \right)$ is $$x = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-\cos t-\sin t+e^{ct} \\
\cos t-\sin t -2e^{ct} \\
\cos t+e^{ct} \end{array} \right)$$

Here $a,b,$ and $c$ are real constants.  What are they?

I found the determinant of the matrix $A = -\lambda^2+2\lambda^2-\lambda-a$, but I'm not sure how I find out what the eigenvalues are supposed to be from the given solution.  Is there anything I can understand about the process to make the simplification easier?

Comment: Hint: What does the third row of **x(t)** tell you about b from  **x(0)**?

Comment: It says that $b=2$.

Comment: Okay, now look at all of the information you have. Can you see the next step you can take from all of this?

Comment: Hint: you have $A$, you know $x$, you can calculate $x'$ and you can you setup $x'$ = $Ax$ and then see if you can multiply out the right side and try to figure out a and c? Make sense?

Comment: Shouldn't I be able to tell what the eigenvalues are of the system based on the solution given?  Then I can just equate my determinant of A to one that solves the system in c?

Comment: Give it a try, there are many ways to approach these problems.

Comment: The determinant has $-\lambda^3$ where you have $-\lambda^2$.

Comment: Is this from a homework, or from an exam? I hope it isn't from an exam.

Comment: The $\cos(t)$ and $\sin(t)$ (which come from the complex exponentials $\e^{it}$ and $e^{-it}$) say that $\pm i$ are eigenvalues.  The characteristic polynomial (which, as joriki noted, should have $-\lambda^3$, not $-\lambda^2$) must be divisible by $(\lambda+i)(\lambda-i) = \lambda^2+1$, and the quotient will tell you what the third eigenvalue is.

Comment: @Robert: You could write that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $\cos(t)$ and $\sin(t)$ (which come from the complex exponentials $e^{it}$ and $e^{-it}$) say that $\pm i$ are eigenvalues.  The characteristic polynomial (which as joriki noted, should have $-\lambda^3$, not $-\lambda^2$) must be divisible by $(\lambda+i)(\lambda-i) = \lambda^2+1$, and the quotient will tell you what the third eigenvalue is.